# Convert an indexed pandas matrix to a flat dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

Given the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', 123, 4, 5, 0, 1], ['foo', 123, 4, 0, 9, 1], ['bar', 33, 0, 0, 3, 5]], columns=list('ABCDEF'))
```

[out]:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   foo 123 4   5   0   1
1   foo 123 4   0   9   1
2   bar 33  0   0   3   5
```

The goal is to sum certain columns ('C', 'D', 'E', F') using other columns ('A' and 'B') as keys to achieve:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   foo 123 8   5   9   2
2   bar 33  0   0   3   5
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()
```

[out]:

```
        C   D   E   F
A   B               
bar 33  0   0   3   5
foo 123 8   5   9   2
```

How do I change it back to the non-indexed matrix? i.e.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   foo 123 8   5   9   2
2   bar 33  0   0   3   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.reset_index()`.

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).sum().reset_index()

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   bar 33  0   0   3   5
1   foo 123 8   5   9   2
```

or

```
df.set_index(['A','B']).sum(level=[0,1]).reset_index()

    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   bar 33  0   0   3   5
1   foo 123 8   5   9   2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter `as_index=False` for return `df`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df1)
     A    B  C  D  E  F
0  bar   33  0  0  3  5
1  foo  123  8  5  9  2
```